# How to restrict user submitted CSS within <div>

Tags: html, css, text-editor

We are having rich text editor in which we can insert html. if any input contains `<style>` tag then the css is applied to entire window.

is it possible to restrict that CSS to be applied within `<div>` not entire window?

Comment: I guess (without HTML 5) you would need to parse the input and add a preceding CSS class or something similar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955592/how-to-restrict-user-submitted-css-within-div

Comment: NOt able to delte post and my account... can anyone help me????

Comment: There's another community "StackOverflow" for questions about code more directly. You probably will get more attention there. This one is more for the process of design behind code and this is because your question is considered off-topic. And it's not for novice users, indeed there are users of all levels asking questions about how to get their design done properly and another advanced things, and believe me this is something not as easy as it seems.

Comment: If you want to delete your account use the form here - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/contact to request it

Comment: @user1620696 yes it was an easy question i got solution from yahoomail/hotmail(mail body content) allows <style> tag in mail. Simplly by parsing css from html and adding an extra condition in css.

Comment: @AjayKumar, I didn't say that your problem wasn't easy. I was saying that the topics about software design people struggle and try to solve here can be hard sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. HTML 5 supports the [scoped attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#A_scoped_stylesheet) on style tags, which restricts styles defined within to being applied only to the descendants of its parent. An example below (shamelessly pulled and edited from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) article).

You could check your user input for style tags and add the `scoped` attribute, if not already present, either before the content is stored, or before you render it to the page.

```
<article>
    <div>
        The scoped attribute allows for you to include style elements mid-document.
        Inside rules only apply to the parent element.
    </div>
    <p>This text should be black. If it is red your browser does not support the scoped attribute.</p>
    <section>
        <style scoped>
            p { color: red; }
        </style>
        <p>This should be red.</p>
        <div>
            <p>This should also be red</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @AndyBrush. i saw u used <style scoped> but in our case end user is submitting the Html+CSS using richTextEditor->insertHtml.
i think i have to modify user input and add an extra attribut "scoped" in <style> tag.

Comment: @AndyBrus i tested it is only supported in firefox :(

Comment: @AjayKumar Oh dear, my apologies! I assumed it'd been implemented by at least FF and Chrome by now.